# DoctrineExtensions SoftDeleteable

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm setting up symfony2 with doctrine2 and I want to use the DoctrineExtensions (Gedmo)
I followed every step, and most is working, but I fail to locate the config file where I need to make changes for the 
SoftDeleteable to work.

https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md

```
$config = new Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;

// Your configs..

$config->addFilter('soft-deleteable', 'Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter');
```

Comment: Check out this description ("Enable the softdeleteable filter"): https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're using symfony 2.0 which includes doctrine 2.1. The version of the DoctrineExtensions you're looking at doesn't support doctrine 2.1.

If you flick to the doctrine2.1.x branch in github it doesn't mention softdeletable unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Ran across this problem myself and fixed it by adding the following to my config.yml

```
doctrine:
    ...
    orm:
        ...
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
```