# Config entries for DoctrineExtensions SoftDeleteable: gedmo/doctrine-extensions

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use `softdelete` option of [gedmo/doctrine-extensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md) but for some reason when I call `romove()`, the record in database gets removed instead of updating `deletedAt` field.

In [here](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md#setup-and-autoloading), doc tells us to update config with:

> $config->addFilter('soft-deleteable',
>   'Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter');

This is just one of the examples I tried:

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true
```

References (just a few of them):

- [DoctrineExtensions SoftDeleteable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056661/doctrineextensions-softdeleteable)
- http://knplabs.com/en/blog/gedmo-doctrine-extensions-on-symfony2
- [Can't enable SoftDeleteable in Symfony2 - Unrecognized options "filters"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374449/cant-enable-softdeleteable-in-symfony2-unrecognized-options-filters)

So the question in simple terms, how do I configure it in config.yml?

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $profile = $this->profileRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

    if (!$profile instanceof Profile) {
        throw new ........
    }

    $this->entityManager->remove($profile);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return true;
}
```

**ENTITY**

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="profile")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 */
class Profile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="deletedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deletedAt;
    ......
}
```

**COMPOSER.JSON**

```
"require": {
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.3.*@dev",
    ......
},
```

**CONFIG.YML**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
      default_connection: front
      connections:
        front:
          driver:   %database_driver%
          host:     %database_host%
          ........
        back:
          driver:   %database_driver%
          host:     %database_host%
          ........


    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager:      front

        entity_managers:
            front:
                connection:       front
                mappings:
                    MyWebsiteBundle:
                        dir:      Entity
                    FOSUserBundle: ~

            back:
                connection:       back
```

**MAPPING INFO:**

```
inanzzz@inanzzz:/var/www/html/local$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:info
Found 8 mapped entities:
[OK]   My\Bundle\Entity\AbstractMerchantProfile
[OK]   My\Bundle\Entity\AbstractIntegration
[OK]   My\Bundle\Entity\APIConsumer
[OK]   My\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Entity\User
[OK]   My\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Profile
[OK]   My\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Integration
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

Included `stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle` in composer.json

`"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",`

Package is [here](https://packagist.org/packages/stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle). Documentation is [here](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst#enable-the-softdeleteable-filter).

Enable bundle in AppKernel:
`new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle()`

Since I have more than one entity managers in config.yml I did:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        em1:
            softdeleteable: true


doctrine:
    dbal:
      default_connection: em1
      connections:
        em1:
          driver:   %database_driver%
          host:     %database_host%
          .......

        em2:
          driver:   %database_driver%
          host:     %database_host%
          .......

        em3:
          driver:   %mws_database_driver%
          host:     %mws_database_host%
          .......

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager:      em1

        entity_managers:
            em1:
                connection:       em1
                mappings:
                    MyWebsiteBundle:
                        dir:      Entity
                    FOSUserBundle: ~
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true

            em2:
                connection:       em2

            em3:
                connection:       em3
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I configured it

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
```